# Knp Snappy Bundle - get number of pages of generated pdf file

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I use Knp Snappy bundle (wkhtmltopdf wrapper) for creating pdf files. I have to know how many pages ther is in the generated pdf file. Is it possible to do it with knp snappy bundle or wkhtmltopdf ?

If not, do you know a fast solution for count the total number of pages of my generated pdf file. My application is made with Symfony 3.

Thanks in advance for your advices.